# Does the non-specified delay in setTimeout function means zero-delay?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Does the non-specified delay in `setTimeout` function means zero-delay?
In other words, is such calling:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //do something
}); // NOTE: no delay specified
```

equal to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //do something
}, 0); // NOTE: zero delay specified
```

?

Comment: Yep, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

 If omitted, the value 0 is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by the [`setTimeout` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), the `delay` is an optional value that will be set to `0` if not specified.

> delay `Optional`
>
> The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should wait before the specified function or code is executed. If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, as soon as possible. Note that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended; see Reasons for delays longer than specified below.

Answer (score 2):

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Alex, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a friendly reminder that when you quote from another site, you need to (A) include a link to that site, and (B) format the quote as a quote (so it doesn't look like you're saying they're your own words). I've fixed up this answer for you, but this way you'll know for next time.